# button_to to <a href ="">

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This should be an easy one but I cannot clock it.... so what I'm trying to achive is to put this:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
  <%= button_to 'Message', conversations_path(sender_id: current_user.id, recipient_id: @user.id), method: 'post', :class => "btn btn-default" %>
</div>
```

In the form of something like this:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
  <a class ="btn btn-default" href="conversations_path(sender_id: current_user.id, recipient_id: @user.id)" role="button"> Message </a>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Any reason to not use `link_to` instead of `button_to`?

Comment: Why not link_to? `link_to 'Message', conversations_path(sender_id: current_user.id, recipient_id: @user.id), class: 'btn btn-default', role: 'button'`

Comment: Thanks for your response @Mat , you are right that does work but I would like to tide up the code a tiny bit more, any thoughts on how can I do so?

Comment: Tide up... what do you mean exactly? `link_to` is the correct way to proceed in this case

Comment: I meant getting rid off these 'sender_id: current_user.id, recipient_id: @user.id)'

Comment: I suppose that you can't avoid the `recipient_id` parameter but I would remove the `sender_id` and get current_user.id inside the controller action. This improve also the security, so you avoid manipulations of that param

Comment: @mat fantastic! thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment:

```
link_to 'Message', conversations_path(sender_id: current_user.id, recipient_id: @user.id), class: 'btn btn-default', role: 'button'
```

link_to because you are requesting a link, not a real button